# Django check every objects of a query to see if have related objects and use this on template

Tags: django, html-table, view, django-class-based-views

I have a template with a table, and there I have all the objects on a query. Each object can have related objects or not. Assuming this, what I need to do is, for each object check if have or not that related object. If not in the table I have a field to put a link to create a related object, but if have show a icon to see this object.

I can do with the one of the "parent" object but I don't know how to do if I have more than one object in the query.

Models to check:

```
class Accident(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    place = models.IntegerField(choices=ACCIDENT_PLACE, default=1)
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
    is_urgency = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                related_name='accidents_created_by',
                editable=False,
                blank=True,
                null=True
                )
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                related_name='accidents_modified_by',
                editable=False,
                blank=True,
                null=True
                )


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "accidente"
        verbose_name_plural = "accidentes"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class AccidentCertificate(models.Model):
    accident = models.ForeignKey(Accident)
    diagnostic = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    return_day = models.DateField()
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    medication = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    presented = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                related_name='acc_certificates_created_by',
                editable=False,
                blank=True,
                null=True
                )
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                related_name='acc_certificates_modified_by',
                editable=False,
                blank=True,
                null=True
                )


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "certificado de accidente"
        verbose_name_plural = "certificados de accidente"
        ordering = ["-id"]


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

this is my view (to check only one object that i already know that have 1 related object)

```
class EmployeeDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    # Chequeamos que el usuario se encuentre logeado
    login_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')

    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employees/detail.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'employee_id'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_object_name = 'employee'
        context = super(EmployeeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        employee = context['employee']
        context['cuil'] = employee.cuil[:2]+'-'+employee.cuil[2:10]+'-'+employee.cuil[-1:]
        # Tomamos los accidentes correspondientes al empleado
        # y los pasamos al contexto
        employee_accidents = Accident.objects.filter(employee=employee)
        context['accidents'] = employee_accidents

        # Tomamos el certificado del accidente si existe
        accident_certificate = AccidentCertificate.objects.get(accident=employee_accidents)
        return context
```

and in the template

```
<table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID Acc.</th>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Cant. Días</th>
                            <th>Locación</th>
                            <th>Detalle</th>
                            <th>Clinica</th>
                            <th>Urgencia</th>
                            <th>Cargado por</th>
                            <th>Certificado</th>
                            <th>Segimiento</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        {% for a in accidents %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ a.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.created|date }}</td>
                            <td>-</td>
                            <td>{{ a.get_place_display }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.detail }}</td>
                            <td>{{ a.clinic }}</td>
                            <td>
                            {% if a.is_urgency %}
                                Si
                            {% else %}
                                No
                            {% endif %}
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ a.created_by }}</td>
                            <td><a href="{% url 'accidents:add_certificate' a.id %}">{% bootstrap_icon "search" %}</a></td>
                            <td>{% bootstrap_icon "search" %}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% empty %}
                        <p class="text-center">
                            <strong>NO HAY REGISTROS</strong>
                        </p>
                        {% endfor %}    
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Well in sintesis I need to take every accidents that correspond to an employee, and for each accident check if this have an AccidentCertificate, if it have put the link in the table to see the certificate, and if not put the link to create the certificate.

Comment: From your models it looks like there can be more than one accident certificates for an accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a count annotation to add the number of related certificates to each accident, then use that number in an if statement in the template.

```
from django.db.models import Count
...
employee_accidents = Accident.objects.filter(employee=employee).annotate(certificate_count=Count('accidentcertificate'))
```

...

```
{% for a in accidents %}
...
{% if a.certificate_count == 0 %}
    <a href="whatever">Add new certificate</a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```